Why would the Suspend function stop working after an update by Software Updater app? Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Yesterday I told the Software Updater app to proceed with the latest updates after being prompted.
Running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS...
When I press the Suspend button the system now locks up... no mouse movement, no response to any key input on keyboard.
Powering off the PC is then the only option.
When I start the system back up it boots normally into the sign on page. Sign on is also normal.
Interestingly, after I power the PC off when it hangs up and then turn the power supply back on the Suspend
button initates the boot just fine.
Is there a good way to isolate this bug or a way to revert back to just before the latest updates?
Suspend has always worked flawlessly taking the desktop down and bringing it back up. Until now....
edit - I believe auto-suspend (based on selected time value) is still functioning...

Reboot. At GRUB, select an older kernel (there might be only one older kernel). See if you can reproduce the problem with that older kernel.
